How to Call Solidity Function with Struct Parameter from JavaScript?
I'm trying to execute a Solidity function using JavaScript. The Solidity function accepts a struct as an argument, and I'm not sure how to structure the data in my JavaScript code to make this call correctly.
Here is the Solidity code:
struct Params {
    address PairAddress;
    uint256 amountIn;
    address[] factories;
    bool tokenToWeth;
    uint256 ToCoinbase;
}

contract Factory {
    function checkPool(Params memory params) external {
        // some logic
    }
}

How can I write a JavaScript function that properly sends data to this Solidity function using  ethers.js?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Assuming that you already know how to initialize a contract instance etc.
This is how you can pass the parameters:
create a Parameter object:
const params = {
  PairAddress: "0xAddress",   
  amountIn: 10000n // the n at the end makes it a bignumber
  factories: ["0xFactoryAddress1", "0xFactoryAddress2"],  
  tokenToWeth: true/false,  
  ToCoinbase: 10000n  
};

Pass it to the contract:
const tx = await YourContractInstance.checkPool(params);


hi, mny thanks but i got this error : code: 'UNEXPECTED_ARGUMENT',
count: 6,
expectedCount: 1,
shortMessage: 'too many arguments: types/values length mismatch'

can you paste your script in the question.

the script you give me .

Hey, I only gave a small snippet, there must be a script that you are running right? The JS  file?

In my code, we pass the struct values in an array form. So instead of creating an object, you should pass the values in an array.
const params = [
  "0xAddress",   
  "10000" // the n at the end makes it a bignumber
  ["0xFactoryAddress1", "0xFactoryAddress2"],  
  "false",  
  "10000"  
];

Pass it to the function as you normally do:
const tx = await YourContractInstance.checkPool(params);

I might be missing an extra array []. If any error occurs, try adding the params in one more array.
